# Need to call a function while Splashscreen in Phonegap

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I want to show a toast on splashscreen in a phonegap app. The toast should be displayed with the splashscreen, not after it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question and a good idea to show additional infos. I just made a test and it works by using this plugins:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-splashscreen

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-x-toast

After the cordova deviceready-event, just call:

```
navigator.splashscreen.show();
```

and then your toast, here the example out from the docs:

```
window.plugins.toast.showWithOptions(
            {
                message: "hey there",
                duration: "short",
                position: "bottom",
                addPixelsY: -40,  // (optional) added a negative value to move it up a bit (default 0)
                data: {} // (optional) pass in a JSON object here (it will be sent back in the success callback below)
            },
            // implement the success callback
            function(result) {
                if (result && result.event) {
                    console.log("The toast was tapped");
                    console.log("Event: " + result.event); // will be defined, with a value of "touch" when it was tapped by the user
                    console.log("Message: " + result.message); // will be equal to the message you passed in
                    console.log("data.foo: " + result.data.foo); // .. retrieve passed in data here
                } else {
                    console.log("The toast has been shown");
                }
            }
        );
```

Comment: I have tried the better and a easier way of doing it. please find my answer bellow.

Answer (score 0):

The most easiest way of doing this is to keep the toast code inside the device ready function. So as and when the app starts the message will be shown with it, along the splashscreen.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() {
       // write your code here
    }
```